# Images not loading in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, intranet

Currently trying to build a company intranet, however the home page images I'm using aren't loading.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="~/Views/Home/Icons/document.png" />
</div>
```

All images are in png format inside a folder next to the cshtml I'm trying to load them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client image elements can not solve "~"

There are two ways to fix this:

1. add `runat="server"` to your image elements
2. use `src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/image/a.jpg")%>'`

UPDATES: sorry, I did not realize you are using MVC.

Then I think you should just move your images out of view folder.  By default any resources under view folder are not accessible from client, that’s why you can not load your image

Comment: Thank you, this has solved the problem. I was getting a bit lost when the other answers to similar questions weren't fixing the issue.

Comment: there is no runat="server" in mvc.

Comment: @Fran check my updates. :) i did not notice he is using mvc at beginning